# How to fix 'Call for undefined function' - PHP, mgp25

Tags: php, function, undefined, call, instagram-api

First and foremost, I've checked dozens of search results including a couple of StackOverflow articles regarding this topic - and no, it doesn't seem like anyone has answered it (even though the question itself might seem similar to some of you)

To sum up the problem: When calling a public function out of the class / calling a method, I get the following error: 'Call to undefined function...'

```
<?php



use InstagramAPI\Exception\ChallengeRequiredException;
use InstagramAPI\Instagram;
use InstagramAPI\Response\LoginResponse;

use InstagramAPI\Exception\RequestHeadersTooLargeException;
use InstagramAPI\Exception\ThrottledException;
use InstagramAPI\Utils;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$username = "name";
$password = "password";

$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram();
    try {
        $ig->login($username, $password);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
        exit(0);
    }

class RequestCollection
{
    /** @var Instagram The parent class instance we belong to. */
    public $ig;
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Instagram $parent The parent class instance we belong to.
     */
    public function __construct(
        $parent)
    {
        $this->ig = $parent;
    }
    /**
     * Paginate the request by given exclusion list.
     *
     * @param Request     $request     The request to paginate.
     * @param array       $excludeList Array of numerical entity IDs (ie "4021088339")
     *                                 to exclude from the response, allowing you to skip entities
     *                                 from a previous call to get more results.
     * @param string|null $rankToken   The rank token from the previous page's response.
     * @param int         $limit       Limit the number of results per page.
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     *
     * @return Request
     */
    protected function _paginateWithExclusion(
        Request $request,
        array $excludeList = [],
        $rankToken = null,
        $limit = 30)
    {
        if (!count($excludeList)) {
            return $request->addParam('count', (string) $limit);
        }
        if ($rankToken === null) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('You must supply the rank token for the pagination.');
        }
        Utils::throwIfInvalidRankToken($rankToken);
        return $request
            ->addParam('count', (string) $limit)
            ->addParam('exclude_list', '['.implode(', ', $excludeList).']')
            ->addParam('rank_token', $rankToken);
    }
    /**
     * Paginate the request by given multi-exclusion list.
     *
     * @param Request     $request     The request to paginate.
     * @param array       $excludeList Array of grouped numerical entity IDs (ie "users" => ["4021088339"])
     *                                 to exclude from the response, allowing you to skip entities
     *                                 from a previous call to get more results.
     * @param string|null $rankToken   The rank token from the previous page's response.
     * @param int         $limit       Limit the number of results per page.
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     *
     * @return Request
     */
    protected function _paginateWithMultiExclusion(
        Request $request,
        array $excludeList = [],
        $rankToken = null,
        $limit = 30)
    {
        if (!count($excludeList)) {
            return $request->addParam('count', (string) $limit);
        }
        if ($rankToken === null) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('You must supply the rank token for the pagination.');
        }
        Utils::throwIfInvalidRankToken($rankToken);
        $exclude = [];
        $totalCount = 0;
        foreach ($excludeList as $group => $ids) {
            $totalCount += count($ids);
            $exclude[] = "\"{$group}\":[".implode(', ', $ids).']';
        }
        return $request
            ->addParam('count', (string) $limit)
            ->addParam('exclude_list', '{'.implode(',', $exclude).'}')
            ->addParam('rank_token', $rankToken);
    }
}


class People extends RequestCollection
{


    public function getInfoByName(
        $username,
        $module = 'feed_timeline')
    {
        return $this->ig->request("users/{$username}/usernameinfo/")
            ->addParam('from_module', $module)
            ->getResponse(new Response\UserInfoResponse());
    }

}

getInfoByName("testuser")
//echo setCloseFriends(["Versaute.Witze", "Instagram"], ["leonie.kai"]);

//$ig->people->setCloseFriends($add = $addinput, $remove = $removeinput, $module = 'favorites_home_list', $source = 'audience_manager');

?>
```

The problem lies within the "getInfoByName" function - which apparently can't be called.
The GitHub rep I'm referring to is the mgp25/Instagram-API.

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Comment: Class methods are not the same as functions, even though both are defined with the `function` keyword. Since `getInfoByName()` is a class method you cannot invoke it independently as you'd do with functions. You need to create a class instance of `People` and then call the method like `$whatever->getInfoByName()`. You can find basic reference at [Classes and Objects](https://www.php.net/oop).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks - I did so previously, but when doing so ($test = new People();) I get following problem:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function RequestCollection::__construct(), 0 passed in ...

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize a new instance of a class.

```
(new People($ig))->getInfoByName('testuser')
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Response\UserInfoResponse' not found in ...
Okay, but I guess this error message doesn't have to do anything with the original problem? or does it?

Comment: It doesn't. You must include necessary class files. That's all. Using `use`

Comment: Okay, makes sense! Thanks a lot - now I got one more "problem" left.
I want to add a feature with which I can add people to the close friends list. The necessary documentation is https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/People.php the function: public function setCloseFriends();
The issues I faced in the thread are comparable to this problem, thus not relevant any longer - though how can I input the two arrays of user lists? Moreover, how can I just add people or just remove people?

Comment: You must merge 2 arrays of user list. Add and remove people using the Instagram API. Please read its documentation.